# C++: Compiler error overriding function from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, compiler-errors

I am attempting to override an abstract class that has been declared inside a DLL in another project, however, when I try to init the overriding class, I receive compilation errors.

These are visual studio projects, as such,the built-in compiler of visual studio are used to compile all code.

I have a template class in a DLL:

```
#ifndef __IINPUT_RECEIVER_H_
#define __IINPUT_RECEIVER_H_

#ifdef HUMANINTERACTION_EXPORTS
#define HUMANINTERACTION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HUMANINTERACTION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace HumanInteraction
{
    template<typename T>
    class HUMANINTERACTION_API IInputReceiver
    {
    public:
        virtual ~IInputReceiver()
        {}

        /**
        * Called when new input is received
        */
        virtual void onInput(const T& refInput) = 0;
    };
}

#endif
```

In another project which is to use this DLL, I inherit from this class and override its method, like so:

```
class Receiver : public IInputReceiver<wchar_t*>
{
public:
    /**
    * Called when new input is received
    */
    virtual void onInput(const wchar_t*& refInput)
    {
        wstring str(refInput);
        wcout << L"Received: " << str << endl;
    }
};
```

But when I try to init an instance of class Receiver I receive the following compilation error; I am omitting unrelated logs:

> 1>c:\users\dominik\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\profile\profile\profile.cpp(25): error C2259: 'Receiver' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>
> 1>          due to following members: 1>          'void
>   HumanInteraction::IInputReceiver::onInput(const T &)' : is abstract

The line profile.cpp(25) attempts to init an instance of Receiver, like so - nothing special here:

```
Receiver receiver;
```

Of course the compiler is right that onInput in the base class in a pure virtual function, however, I override this function in my derived class. Therefore, the class Receiver is not abstract as the log indicates.

Though usually I tend to fix my issues on my own, I have absolutely no clue whatsoever this time why this error is occuring - absolutely void.

I would greatly appreciate any contribution to this problem, even if it is 'only' comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the `virtual` member function in the base class is

```
virtual void onInput(const T& refInput) = 0;
```

The one in the derived class is

```
virtual void onInput(const wchar_t*& refInput)
```

What you need to use is:

```
virtual void onInput(wchar_t* const& refInput)
```

It will make more sense if you use

```
virtual void onInput(T const& refInput) = 0;
```

in the base class.